# can't install strongloop inside Vagrant

Tags: node.js, vagrant, strongloop

I managed to install it on my host OSX box but can't seem to get it to install inside vagrant:

http://pastebin.com/RQkuHb82

Any ideas?

#### Editor's notes, paste the error message here:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/vagrant$ npm install -g strongloop
 
> heapdump@0.2.10 install /home/vagrant/.nvm/v0.10.33/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/strong-supervisor/node_modules/heapdump
> node-gyp rebuild
 
make: Entering directory `/home/vagrant/.nvm/v0.10.33/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/strong-supervisor/node_modules/heapdump/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/heapdump/src/heapdump.o
make: g++: Command not found
make: *** [Release/obj.target/heapdump/src/heapdump.o] Error 127
make: Leaving directory `/home/vagrant/.nvm/v0.10.33/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/strong-supervisor/node_modules/heapdump/build'
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/home/vagrant/.nvm/v0.10.33/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-43-generic
gyp ERR! command "node" "/home/vagrant/.nvm/v0.10.33/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/vagrant/.nvm/v0.10.33/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/strong-supervisor/node_modules/heapdump
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.33
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing heapdump@0.2.10
 
> strong-fork-syslog@1.2.1 install /home/vagrant/.nvm/v0.10.33/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/strong-supervisor/node_modules/strong-fork-syslog
> node-gyp rebuild
 
make: Entering directory `/home/vagrant/.nvm/v0.10.33/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/strong-supervisor/node_modules/strong-fork-syslog/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/syslog/syslog.o
make: g++: Command not found
make: *** [Release/obj.target/syslog/syslog.o] Error 127
make: Leaving directory `/home/vagrant/.nvm/v0.10.33/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/strong-supervisor/node_modules/strong-fork-syslog/build'
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/home/vagrant/.nvm/v0.10.33/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:267:23)
stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-43-generic
gyp ERR! command "node" "/home/vagrant/.nvm/v0.10.33/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/vagrant/.nvm/v0.10.33/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/strong-supervisor/node_modules/strong-fork-syslog
 ERR! node -v v0.10.33
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing strong-fork-syslog@1.2.1
 
> strong-agent@1.2.1 install /home/vagrant/.nvm/v0.10.33/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/strong-agent
> node-gyp rebuild || exit 0
 
make: Entering directory `/home/vagrant/.nvm/v0.10.33/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/strong-agent/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/strong-agent/src/strong-agent.o
make: g++: Command not found
make: *** [Release/obj.target/strong-agent/src/strong-agent.o] Error 127
make: Leaving directory `/home/vagrant/.nvm/v0.10.33/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/strong-agent/build'
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/home/vagrant/.nvm/v0.10.33/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:12)
 ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-43-generic
gyp ERR! command "node" "/home/vagrant/.nvm/v0.10.33/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/vagrant/.nvm/v0.10.33/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/strong-agent
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.33
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.1
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Comment: Just say it doens't work is not good way to raise a question. You need give detail about your question, why it is not running, such as the error message, `Vagrantfile` content, system environment. If you have these informations somewhere, for example, in that url, you need paste here, link will be gone anytime.

Comment: from the error message, you didn't install pre-compiler software, such as g++:  `make: g++: Command not found`, DO review the `strongloop` installation document to find out all dependencies.

Comment: great， I should answer it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your VM doesn't have G++ installed, you can get round this by install the build-essential package which includes a number of "essential" packages required for compiling C & C++ code (amongst other things).

The vagrantfile in the strongloop repo installs this and a few other pages, so you might want to update your bootstrap to install the following as well

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

I'd add it to your bootstrap file or provisioning playbooks/recipes etc for future use.

**EDIT**:

The vagrantfile in the strongloop repo installs this and a few other pages, so you might want to update your bootstrap to install the additional packages the following as well

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential git curl vim
```

Comment: git should also be installed as part of this bootstrapping, since some of the functionality requires it. See also: https://github.com/strongloop-community/strongbox